# Understanding the Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series, normed-spaces, fourier-transform

> I am studying the properties of the Fourier transform.
>   Fourier transform: $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{it\xi}dt\:\:,\:\: \xi\in\mathbb{R}$$

**Notes**: If $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})\\||f||=\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt<\infty$

$\hat{f}(\xi)\in C_B(\mathbb{R})\\||g||_{C_B(\mathbb{R})}=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|g(t)|$

Then $\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\leqslant\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}||f||_1$

**Observation**: I tried to understand this notes on Fourier transform in the following way:

I want to prove $\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}}|\hat{f}(\xi)|\leqslant\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}||f||_1$ and I started using:
$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{it\xi}dt\leqslant\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it\xi}dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}||f||_1\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it\xi}dt$

However I guess after computation that  $\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it\xi}dt=0$.

**Questions:**

**1)** What do you think of what I have done so far? How can I prove the property?

**2)** Fourier transform here presented is $\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{it\xi}dt$. However in books I find $2\pi$ instead of $\sqrt{2\pi}$. Does this formula intends to compute the coefficients? How should I derive it with functional analysis tools?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any comments will be welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid, for $e^{it\xi}\notin L^{1}$.

Rather, the trick is to use absolute value into the integrals:

\begin{align*}
|\widehat{f}(\xi)|&=\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{it\xi}dt\right|\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)e^{it\xi}|dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\|f\|_{L^{1}(-\infty,\infty)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The constant depends on the authors.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by the constant? Any thoughts on my second question?

Comment: The $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. Yes, that formula is to derive the coefficients of Fourier series in a compact way.

Comment: When I tried to derive the Fourier coefficient I used a projection over $e^{it\xi}$ for the space of periodic functions in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. Unfortunately I am not understanding on how the coefficients differ from the transform. Is the transform the coefficient? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should say it precisely, for the Fourier series coefficients, the interval is $[-\pi,\pi]$, not $(-\infty,\infty)$, and this version is to use for the theory of singular integrals.

Comment: Sorry for bothering. What do you mean by theory of singular integrals?

Comment: You may search about Hilbert transform, Riesz transform, or some sort like that, and Fourier multiplier.